# aero with very large window sizes

Tags: aero

when i create multiple really large windows with opengl (2 windows, each of them 13440+1080 pixels) aero turns off resulting in animation tearing. The video card (W8000) has 4GB memory, so there should be enough video ram.

a) is there a setting anywhere that limits the maximum windows size under aero?

b) can i still activate double-buffered/vsynced rendering? enforcing blank-to-vsync or opengl triple buffering does not work

Comment: run ProcessExplorer or ProcessHacker and look in the System Information Windows how much free GPU RAM you have when Aero turns off.

Comment: we checked with process explorer, (there are two cards) 2x4GB=8GB was reported but when the window opens and aero turns off, 1.5 GB are reported as used, so 2.5GB should be left over

Comment: why do you need such a large window? What is your Monitor resolution.

Comment: We attach 14 monitors with Full HD (1920x1080) to a system for large-scale opengl effects system. building a single system is simpler and more cost effective than distributing across multiple computers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft knows an answer to a similar qustion:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2724530

> This problem occurs when Desktop Window Manager attempts to display a
>   desktop that is larger than 8192 pixels high or 8192 pixels wide. This
>   exceeds the maximum allowable size for a DirectX 10 texture. (In
>   Windows 7, the Desktop Window Manager utilizes DirectX 10.)

So in our situation DWM is disabled. We have to reconfigure the desktop to reenable it.